# How to fix navbar actionlink to the right side

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, model-view-controller

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Moto Technic", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Anasayfa", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Motosikletler", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("En Son Eklenenler", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li style="text-align:right; display:block">@Html.ActionLink("Giriş Yap", "Login","Home")</li>
                <li style="">@Html.ActionLink("Üye Ol","Register","Home")</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Guys, I want to put `Uye ol` and `Giris Yap` action links to the right side but text align doesn't work. Do you know what to do? I'm working with MVC and I don't know what to do at this time. Whatever I add, it is put on the left side but when I text style `text-align:right` it doesn't work...

Comment: without seeing any of the css you have its tough to say. Maybe float? or are you just trying to put the text of the li to align right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying the style to the

> ul

instead of the

> li